# How strtok_r function return values?

Tags: c++, c

I am doing component test for a 'C' code. I have read the functionality of **strtok_r** function but I am not able to get the return value that I want to pass in **strncmp**' function. My code is contains **strtok_r** and **strncmp** functions as below:

```
typedef struct BufferN {
    uint32_t v;
    uint32_t m;
} My_Buffer;

char subsystemstr[64] = { '\0' };
My_Buffer buffer;
char *p_system;
char *p_subsystem;

(void) GetString(&buffer, subsystemstr, sizeof(subsystemstr));
p_system = strtok_r (subsystemstr, ":", &p_subsystem);

for (i = 0u; i < 100; i++) 
{
    if (strncmp(p_system, "all", 64) == 0) 
    {
       /*Some Code Statement*/
    }
}
```

Since array **subsystemstr** is initialized to '\0', I am modifying this array value with the help of function **GetString** as below:

```
strncpy(subsystemstr, "all:", 64);
```

When I am printing **subsystemstr**, I am having updated array as:

```
["all:", '\0' <repeats 59 times>]
```

but when I am printing **p_system**(return value of strtok_r). I am getting

```
[0x388870 ""]
```

I am confused how it is working. Actually I want value of p_system = **"all"** so that 'strncmp' function can **return 0.**
Please suggest.

Comment: Add `printf("subsystemstr=%s\n",subsystemstr);` after `GetString` and before the `strtok` call and `printf("p_system=%s\n", p_system);` after `strtok`.  What does it output?

Comment: It is giving the same output to me ["all:", '\0' <repeats 59 times>] and [0x388870 ""]

Comment: @AshA: `printf("p_system=%s\n", p_system)` will not print `[0x3888770 ""]` :) However, it would also be useful to have `printf("subsystemstr = %p;  p_system = %p\n", subsystemstr, p_system);` in order to understand what p_system is pointing at. Finally, `strncmp` shouldn't be necessary here (unless you suspect you might buffer overrun subsystemstr, and you should avoid doing that instead :) ) and neither `strncmp` nor `strcmp` will return 0 when comparing "all:" with "all". (unless you force the comparison to be 3 characters using `strncmp(..., 3);`)

Comment: Since you tagged this a C++, save yourself some frustration and use `std::string` and its many `find` methods.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I am not frustated, I think you do not have good reading skills. As I mentioned I am doing testing so I can not modify the code..

Comment: @rici Thank You for your suggestion. I know printf("p_system=%s\n", p_system) will not print [0x3888770 ""] :) 
As I mentioned I am performing testing so I can not modify the code to put printf but as an alternative I am using the command 'p p_system' in command line debugger and getting [0x3888770 ""].
One more thing I would like to share what I think here that strncmp will return 0 when comparing "all" with "all" as strtok_r will return token "all" after delimiting the string "all:" by delimiter ":"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your understanding of what

```
p p_system
```

actually does (prints the address of p_system)
in gdb, the command would be

```
p *p_system
```

or, using the builtin printf command

```
printf "%s", p_system
```

or, using the C function

```
call printf("%s", p_system)
```

or,

```
call (void)puts(p_system)
```

or, if you do not mind also seeing some address values

```
x /s p_system
```

Comment: your suggestion really works for me to get the values of  p_system. Thanks.